# Layout issue with the Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, uistackview

Swift layout issue. I want to set my stackView at the bottom part. I set the proper constrain even my stackView not fix at the correct place. Here is the attach image.
[image]
[image]

Here is my Constrain Setup.
[image]

Can you please explain what is the actual problem.I have same issues with my same other app also.

Comment: What's constant of bottom constraint of stack view ?

Comment: Can button constraint of actual width and height?

Comment: I want to fix it with the sideView leading /trailing and the bottom with 0 constant and fixed height is 70. SagarChauhan

Comment: no it is not in actual size in picture. @AbhishekJadhav

Comment: Then set button actual width and height then embed in stackview then simply set constraints leading and traling

Comment: is there any auto layout error in the console?

Comment: no there no such error. @MetinGuler

Comment: please share xcode structure for view controller and any code you may have written for this. Please share exact constraints you have used. Check size inspector in xcode and share

Answer (score 0):

I notice your storyboard view and simulator view seem to be different devices - have you set the 0 bottom constraint equal to the bottom of the safe area, or the superview? And does it do the same thing when you use a different simulator (I.e the same as the view used in your storyboard)?

Edit: sorry just realised the first and second images were both different simulators.  My question on where you’ve set the constraint stands, though.